# Cannot read property 'data' of undefined in ReactJs and SwaggerUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, httprequest

I am working with ReactJs and Fetch API from Swagger UI. I code for Room management, this is my code for that

In `actions.js` file

```
// Room type  action
export const actFetchRoomTypesRequest = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return callApi('admin/host-room-types', 'GET', null).then((res) => {
            dispatch(actFetchRoomTypes(res.data));
        });
    };
};

export const actFetchRoomTypes = (roomTypes) => {
    return {
        type: Types.FETCH_ROOMTYPES,
        roomTypes,
    };
};

export const actDeleteRoomTypeRequest = (id) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return callApi(`admin/host-room-types/${id}`, 'DELETE', null).then((res) => {
            dispatch(actFetchRoomTypesRequest());
        });
    };
};

export const actAddRoomTypeRequest = (roomType) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return callApi(`admin/host-room-types`, 'POST', roomType).then((res) => {
            return callApi(`admin/host-room-types`).then((ress) => {
                dispatch(actFetchRoomTypes(ress.data));
            });
        });
    };
};

export const actAddRoomType = (roomType) => {
    return {
        type: Types.ADD_ROOMTYPE,
        roomType,
    };
};

export const actGetRoomTypeRequest = (id) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return callApi(`admin/host-room-types/${id}`, 'GET', null).then((res) => {
            dispatch(actGetRoomType(res.data));
        });
    };
};

export const actGetRoomType = (roomType) => {
    return {
        type: Types.EDIT_ROOMTYPE,
        roomType,
    };
};

export const actUpdateRoomTypeRequest = (roomType) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return callApi(`admin/host-room-types/${roomType.id}`, 'PUT', roomType).then((res) => {
            return callApi(`admin/host-room-types`).then((ress) => {
                dispatch(actFetchRoomTypes(ress.data));
            });
        });
    };
};

export const actUpdateRoomType = (roomType) => {
    return {
        type: Types.UPDATE_ROOMTYPE,
        roomType,
    };
};
```

In `RoomTypeItem.js` which the place I show all action for that

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class RoomTypeItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log('constructor');
    }

    onDelete = (id) => {
        console.log(id);
        if (window.confirm('ban muon xoa?')) {
            this.props.onDelete(id);
        }
    };
    onSelectRoomType = (id) => {
        console.log('onSelect' + id);
        this.props.onSelect(id);
    };
    render() {
        var { roomType, index } = this.props;
        console.log('render' + roomType.id + this.props.checked);
        return (
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input
                        type="checkbox"
                        className="delid[]"
                        checked={this.props.checked}
                        onChange={() => this.onSelectRoomType(roomType.id)}
                    />
                </td>
                <td>{index + 1}</td>
                <td>{roomType.name}</td>
                <td>{roomType.description}</td>
                <td>
                    <Link to={`/roomType/${roomType.id}/edit`} className="btn btn-warning mr-10">
                        Update
                    </Link>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
export default RoomTypeItem;
```

And in `RoomTypeActionPage` have code like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { actAddRoomTypeRequest, actGetRoomTypeRequest, actUpdateRoomTypeRequest } from './../../actions/index';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class RoomTypeActionPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            id: '',
            txtName: '',
            txtDescription: '',
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var { match } = this.props;
        if (match) {
            var id = match.params.id;
            this.props.onEditRoomType(id);
        }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps && nextProps.itemEditing) {
            var { itemEditing } = nextProps;
            this.setState({
                id: itemEditing.id,
                txtName: itemEditing.name,
                txtDescription: itemEditing.description,
            });
        }
    }

    onChange = (e) => {
        var target = e.target;
        var name = target.name;
        var value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        this.setState({
            [name]: value,
        });
    };
    onSave = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        var { id, txtName, txtDescription } = this.state;
        var { history } = this.props;
        var roomType = {
            id: id,
            name: txtName,
            description: txtDescription,
        };
        if (id) {
            //update
            this.props.onUpdateRoomType(roomType);
        } else {
            this.props.onAddRoomType(roomType);
        }
        history.goBack();
    };
    render() {
        var { txtName, txtDescription } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                <form onSubmit={this.onSave}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Name:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            name="txtName"
                            value={txtName}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Description:</label>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            className="form-control"
                            name="txtDescription"
                            value={txtDescription}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <Link to="/roomType-list" className="btn btn-danger mr-10">
                        Cancel
                    </Link>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                        Save
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        itemEditing: state.itemEditing,
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, props) => {
    return {
        onAddRoomType: (roomType) => {
            dispatch(actAddRoomTypeRequest(roomType));
        },

        onEditRoomType: (id) => {
            dispatch(actGetRoomTypeRequest(id));
        },

        onUpdateRoomType: (roomType) => {
            dispatch(actUpdateRoomTypeRequest(roomType));
        },
    };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(RoomTypeActionPage);
```

And this is my `Reducer`

```
import * as Types from './../constants/ActionTypes';
var initialState = {
    loading: false,
    data: [],
};

var findIndex = (roomTypes, id) => {
    var result = -1;
    roomTypes.data.forEach((roomType, index) => {
        if (roomType.id === id) {
            result = index;
        }
    });
    return result;
};

const roomTypes = (state = initialState, action) => {
    var index = -1;
    var { id, roomType } = action;

    switch (action.type) {
        case Types.FETCH_ROOMTYPES:
            state = action.roomTypes;
            return { ...state };
        case Types.DELETE_ROOMTYPE:
            index = findIndex(state, id);
            state.splice(index, 1);
            return { ...state };
        case Types.ADD_ROOMTYPE:
            state.data.push(action.roomType);
            return { ...state };
        case Types.UPDATE_ROOMTYPE:
            index = findIndex(state, roomType.id);
            state[index] = roomType;
            return { ...state };
        default:
            return { ...state };
    }
};

export default roomTypes;
```

I do not know when I run my code it shows me an error like this

[image]

I already to check all but I can realize where I code wrong for that. PLease help me, I need you, Thank thank so much
This is my link for swagger UI : [here](https://town-house-api-seven-team.herokuapp.com/swagger-ui.html#/host45room45type45controller)

This is my apiCaller

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as Config from './../constants/Config';

export default function callApi(endpoint, method = 'GET', body) {
    return axios({
        method: method,
        url: `${Config.API_URL}/${endpoint}`,
        data: body,
        headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization:
                'Bearer ' +
                'eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTU5Njg4MTYxMSwiZXhwIjoxNjEyOTQzNjEwfQ.eXkXWuuIMk94uOtVZQSNysbfJyIQuP5dIFqS06Kx-KsYVCkVEAbU01IhwJpkR4YtgXt8idkN4MM0cT76Xre7Sg',
        },
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: All the code you have shown is irrelevant to that error. The problem seems to be that the promise that `callApi` returns doesn't resolve with anything. It calls your callback in the `.then()` handler with `undefined` which is why you see the error "Cannot read property 'data' of undefined" when trying to access `res.data`. It even marks the exact line where the error occurs. Please show us the code for `callApi`.

Comment: I already updated my question, could you please check it again

Comment: Did you check if the request completes successfully? Open the network tab in your developer tools and force the code to be called to see if it works.

Comment: I have see that it already get right ID but about the Data it cannot get that, I do not know why

Comment: Also from looking at your swagger api description I can't see a detail endpoint on `host-room-types` that accepts a `GET` with an `id` provided.

Comment: How can I fix that, I do not know how? because I have to do the same with city management but it works, why does the RoomType is not

Comment: If I `curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'https://town-house-api-seven-team.herokuapp.com/api/admin/host-room-types/1'` it responds with `405 Method Not Allowed`. You have only defined a list endpoint but not a detail endpoint. That needs to be changed on the server that provides that api.